# Monthly data versus yearly prediction

Tags: correlation

How would you see the relation of a monthly variable categorical with a yearly target value float for differents years in order to predict.

In the farming industry the relation is not so simple for categorical values as the drought level , like pre-harvest period has more weight for some months on the yearly result because some months are more relevant.

What kind of null hypothesis test would you do for with both variables to conclude
I was thinking of anova
Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider each month as an explanatory variable. And the year as response variable. Because, **for each year, you'll have 12 monthly variables**.

With a model, you could find the relationship that has each month value with the final output. For that, you can perform a linear model (your categorical variables will or must be recoded as dummy variables for that estimation).

If you want to check the effect of the variable by itself. `Yearly Target = a * Monthly Variable`. I agree with @Leevo.

Comment: thank you , migh be difficult but I will be trying to do a linear model based on my months but I still dont have the target variable as the results  I dont have the final output

Answer (score -3):

You can use linear or Loess interpolation. Alternatively you can take monthly averages in case aggregation is not a problem for your task.

Comment: Yes but in the farming industry the relation is not so simple as the pre-harvest period has more weight on the yearly resul than other monthst. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This information wasn't present in the question. Please update it with all the details, otherwise other users won't be able to help you.

Comment: These considerations are independent from the actual time series that you're trying to build. If some part of the time series are more relevant than other, that should result from the statistical models that you run on those data.